# I don't have permission for editing www-data:www-data files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

OK, so i recently installed Ubuntu for web development and i noticed 2 things:

1. I need to use `$ sudo` for editing files (in www-data: ... file / s), for example`$ sudo atom / var / www / index.html`. If i do not use this command, atom will say i not have the permission.
2. I also need to use `$ sudo` for somes commands, for example for`$ git commit -m`new commiti will need to use`$ sudo`. But it's probably because git don't have the right permissions.

I tryed `$ sudo chown -R www-data: anatole` (anatole is my username on ubuntu) but wordpress need www-data: www -data permission for adding plugins ...

I think i'm root cause i can use sudo commands and i'm the only user on this computer.

So if somone have the solution i'm realy intrested to know it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can give yourself write rights in the /var/www directory:

   - add yourself to the www-data group using `addgroup $USER www-data`. You will have to log out and back in for this to take effect. Check with `groups`
   - give all group memebers write access using `chmod g+w /var/www -R` in the directory tree.
2. It sounds as if you have your git repository right in /var/www. This is bad security practice, because you could very well end up exposing your git repository on the web. I know that this may not be an issue on the development machine, but this may change without your being aware of it. I would move the .git repository out of the directory. You could use some kind of access control like .htaccess or deny www-data access to the .git directory but this can break, easily. I would probably use symlinks to the files and directories.

Comment: Thanks you so much you just fix my first problem :D 
But how can i work with git without a git repo in /var/www ?

Comment: And i can also use a gitignore, no ?

Comment: I would use symlinks for the files needed in the /var/www directory, this guarantees that no files can be exposed in /var/www which you don't want but allows direct editing of the files in the development directory and in /var/www without getting out of sync. git will be happy with the files in the development directory.